# React - How to prevent rerender when using curried function

Tags: reactjs

Sometimes we make a click handler for few ui components
E.g.

```
const getItemClickHandler = (id) => () => setActive(id);

<Item onClick={getItemClickHandler(someId)} />
```

However if we want to add useCallback() to prevent rerender of the item component, it will fail because every times the function returned by getItemClickHandler is “different”

What can I do to prevent rerender but wanna use curried function?

Comment: Do you pass `getItemClickHandler` function to child components or the result of calling `getItemClickHandler` function?

Comment: @Yousaf I have updated the code above.

Comment: You are passing the result of calling `getItemClickHandler` function, so `useCallback` is useless here. Either don't use a higher order function or just pass `getItemClickHandler` to `Item` component and let the `Item` component call `getItemClickHandler` function. In this case. wrapping `getItemClickHandler` in `useCallback` hook will prevent unnecessary re-render.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it simply.
Create a wrapper around the item or into modify item self, define callback like this.

```js
function Item({id, onClick}){
const _onClick = useCallback(() => onClick(id),[id,onClick]);

retun <div onClick={_onClick} />
}
```

So in the parent component use the Item like this:

```js
const itemClickHandler = useCallback((id) => setActive(id),[]);

<Item onClick={itemClickHandler} id={1} />
<Item onClick={itemClickHandler} id={2}/>
```

Comment: why do you use `useCallback` in one case but not the other?

Comment: We should use `useCallback` in both, I edited answer.